# Video src tag not working on chrome but working fine on mozilla

Tags: javascript

I'm working on making this video autoplay on chrome but it's not working. It's working fine on mozilla

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none" align = "center">
  <video autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" poster  width="600" height="340">
    <source src="https://holisticneurodevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Directions-0-jWvIA2RoWs_beta.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://holisticneurodevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Directions-0-jWvIA2RoWs_beta.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video> 
</div>
<div id="dialog2" style="display: none" align = "center">
  <video autoplay loop preload="auto" poster  width="600" height="340" >
    <source src="https://holisticneurodevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Directions-0-jWvIA2RoWs_beta.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://holisticneurodevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Directions-0-jWvIA2RoWs_beta.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

They both not working on chrome please help

Comment: can you please correct your question?

Comment: Sorry The auto play on chrome is not working,working fine on mozilla

Comment: Chrome prevents autoplaying video, which I think is a good thing... Advertiser used to put sound in there iframes. So annoying! In order to autoplay a video you have to mute the video or either play it in some user interaction event. You would need to build a hole SPA application to get something like youtube's autoplaying when switching page/video

Comment: I have downloaded the video on wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Its working on my chrome when i disable the display:none in your styling. Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" style="display: one" align = "center">
  <video autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" poster  width="600" height="340">
    <source src="https://holisticneurodevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Directions-0-jWvIA2RoWs_beta.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://holisticneurodevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Directions-0-jWvIA2RoWs_beta.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video> 
</div>
<div id="dialog2" style="display: one" align = "center">
  <video autoplay loop preload="auto" poster  width="600" height="340" >
    <source src="https://holisticneurodevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Directions-0-jWvIA2RoWs_beta.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://holisticneurodevelopment.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Directions-0-jWvIA2RoWs_beta.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```